# Unable to run a Docker image with a Rust executable

Tags: docker, rust, dockerfile

I am trying to create an image with my binary file (written in Rust) but I get different errors. This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM scratch
COPY binary /
COPY .env /
COPY cert.pem /etc/ssl/
ENV RUST_BACKTRACE 1
CMD /binary
```

Building finishes fine but when I try to run it I get this:

```
$ docker run binary
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/sh\": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory": unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

And this:

```
$ docker run binary /binary
standard_init_linux.go:195: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

I have no idea what to do. The error message looks very odd to me. According to the [official Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/baseimages/#create-a-simple-parent-image-using-scratch) it must work.

System info: latest Arch Linux and Docker:

```
Docker version 18.02.0-ce, build fc4de447b5
```

I tested with a C++ program and it works fine, with both clang and gcc.

It does not work with `scratch`, `alpine`, `busybox` ,or  `bash`-based images, but it does work with `postgresql`, `ubuntu`, and `debian` images.  The exact problem is something related to Rust and lightweight docker images - everything works okay otherwise.

Comment: CP: https://github.com/docker-library/hello-world/issues/44

Comment: It may be unrelated to rust, check the following issue https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/17896

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As @Oleg Sklyar pointed out, the problem is that the Rust binary is dynamically-linked.

This may be a bit confusing because many people who have heard of Rust have also heard that Rust binaries are statically-linked, but this refers to the Rust code in crates: crates are linked statically because they are all known at the moment of compilation. This does not refer to existing C dynamic libraries that the program may link to, such as libc and other must-have libraries. Often times, these libraries can also be built as statically-linked artifacts (see the end of this post). To check whether your program or library is dynamically-linked, you can use `ldd` utility:

```
$ ldd target/release/t
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe43797000)
    libdl.so.2 => /usr/lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fa78482d000)
    librt.so.1 => /usr/lib/librt.so.1 (0x00007fa784625000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fa784407000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fa7841f0000)
    libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa783e39000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa784ca2000)
```

You'll need these libraries in your Docker image. You will also need the interpreter; to get its path you can use `objdump` utility:

```
$ LANG=en objdump -s -j .interp target/release/t

target/release/t:     file format elf64-x86-64

Contents of section .interp:
 0270 2f6c6962 36342f6c 642d6c69 6e75782d  /lib64/ld-linux-
 0280 7838362d 36342e73 6f2e3200           x86-64.so.2.
```

Copy the files into the expected directories and everything works okay.

There is also a second option which is to use the [`rust-musl-builder`](https://hub.docker.com/r/ekidd/rust-musl-builder/) docker image. There are some problems with `postgresql` and `diesel` but for most of projects it would be good. It works by producing a statically-linked executable which you may just copy and use. This option is much more preferred than using an interpreter and dynamic libraries if you want to provide a docker image with less size and without having all that useless extra data such as interpreter, unused libraries and so on.

Comment: I would *not* just copy libraries (and especially *not* the interpreter) from the compiling system to the Docker image. You should instead install the libraries within the Docker image using the distribution's package manager and then build the Rust program inside the container, linking to the appropriate libraries automatically. You could also choose to build a static binary using MUSL.

Comment: The example in the question is just a hello-world app, my real binary has a lot of dynamic libraries which don't have static version. The interpreter is also a good question - without it we can't run anything anyway. I want to build a docker image with `scratch` base image. Do you suggest me to use `rust` base image, compile anything there, and then copy binaries and everything else from it into the `scratch` base image (double `FROM` Dockerfile section)?

Comment: Like that? https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#before-multi-stage-builds

If so, what will be the difference? And what is so special about interpreter?

Comment: Yes, a multistage build is the right tool for that; you don't want to ship around the Rust compiler in your final image. I've never once even heard of someone copying the interpreter between machines, so that just feels super suspicious.The Rust playground is a static binary, so you can go pretty far with static linking, but you are right that at some point it becomes complicated. There are images like [rust-musl-builder](https://github.com/emk/rust-musl-builder) to make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was that I was passing an invalid executable name:

```sh
CMD ["liquidator"]
```

`liquidator` was the name of the Docker image, but I needed this:

```sh
CMD ["hifi-liquidator"]
```

Basically the CMD must be the same as the "name" field in the `Cargo.toml` file.